# Control Tab - Is there a way to customize the "Available Processes" list to be " Collapse All" always

Tags: blueprism

In Blue Prism in the Control Tab, Is there a way to customize the "Available Processes" list to be " Collapse All" always?
Also, can the width of the columns be predefined or saved once set?

I have not found any way to save settings.
Are there some `ini` file of registry settings controlling that?

Comment: Any ini settings are stored in the DB, dont think they can be saved the way your asking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Have looked through the database in Blue prism, the help files and various forums. Nothing turns up any ability currently to set the setting the way you requested or have it stored in the DB backend.